# How can I map inheritance with subclasses

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, mapping, subclass

I have a baseclass that IS NOT abstract and two classes that is based on this class but which have different implemenations in how they calculate the result. The baseclass also inherits from an abstract class that is shared in many different places in the system so I cannot really change that one.

I know that I could extract a baseclass that all three inherits from and just use a normal mapping with subclasses but I just want to know if it is possible to create a hbm file that maps this scenario.

```
class BaseClass : CalculationBaseClass
{
   public virtual int Calculate()
   {
     ...
   }
}

class SpecializedClass : BaseClass
{
   public override int Calculate()
   {
      ...
   }
}

class HistoricClass : BaseClass
{
   public override int Calculate()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve- can you specify what you'd like your table structure to look like?

Answer (score 0):

From NHibernate [documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-8-inheritance-mapping#):

> NHibernate supports the three basic inheritance mapping strategies.
>
> - table per class hierarchy
> - table per subclass
> - table per concrete class

You would choose one of the strategies based on what you current table structure is, or if you don't have legacy schema you can just choose the one that is most appropriate for you object model (based on mapped properties for example). In your case, if you use 'table per class hierarchy' you would end up with mapping like this:

```
<class name="CalculationBaseClass" table="MyTable">
    <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="TYPE" type="String"/>

    <subclass name="BaseClass" discriminator-value="BASE">
        ...
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="SpecializedClass" discriminator-value="SPECIALIZED">
        ...
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="HistoricClass " discriminator-value="HISTORIC">
        ...
    </subclass>
</class>
```